# How to make QGraphicsView update after changing a QGraphicsPixmapItem

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I'm quite a n00b with Qt, but I have seen a lot of posts where people can't get a `QGraphicsView` to update as expected. I am trying to make very simple widget that will display two arrays of data as images overlapped with some alpha blending. From what I gather the best way to do this is to create a `QImage` to hold the image data, and each time I want to update the overlay display, you convert the `QImage` into a `QPixmap`, and then use that to update the pixmap of a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` (which is in a `QGraphicsScene`, which is in a `QGraphicsView`).

As a minimum working example, I have it setup to generate a random red image and random green image, and with random blending between them. It's setup on a timer to generate new data and, ideally, update the view. No matter how many updates/repaints I drop around, I can't seem to get it to update properly. The timer seems to be working, and the random data generation seems to be working as well, but the scene only updates if I physically change the size of the window.

Here is my code, in a few blocks. First `DisplayWidget.h`

```
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include "ui_displaywidget.h"
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "math.h"
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <qsize.h>
#include <qtimer.h>

#define FULLSCALE 255
#define IM_X_MIN -5.0
#define IM_X_MAX 5.0
#define IM_Z_MIN 0.0
#define IM_Z_MAX 15.0
#define IM_PIXEL_WIDTH 200
#define IM_PIXEL_HEIGHT IM_PIXEL_WIDTH * (IM_Z_MAX-IM_Z_MIN)/(IM_X_MAX - IM_X_MIN)
#define BORDER_WIDTH    10
#define RAND_SEED 7

class DisplayWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    DisplayWidget(int width, int height, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~DisplayWidget();

    void SetData(float * data, float minVal, float maxVal);
    void SetTransparency(float * alpha, float minVal, float maxVal);

private:
    //Ui::DisplayWidgetClass ui;
    QGraphicsView * view;
    QGraphicsScene * scene;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem * bModeItem;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem * dModeItem;
    QImage * bImage;
    QImage * dImage;
    QTimer * frameGrab;


    void CreateWidgets();
    void SetupGui();

    int w, h;

public slots:
    void GenerateNewData();
};
```

And here's the relevant parts of my .cpp. `GenerateNewData()` is the function that doesn't seem to produce updates to the scene. This is where I have tried view/scene/item updates/repaints.

```
DisplayWidget::DisplayWidget(int width, int height, QWidget *parent): QWidget(parent)
{
    w = width;
    h = height;

    CreateWidgets();
    SetupGui();

    // seed the random number generator
    srand(RAND_SEED);
    GenerateNewData();
}

void DisplayWidget::CreateWidgets()
{
    view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    bModeItem = scene->addPixmap(QPixmap());
    dModeItem = scene->addPixmap(QPixmap());
    bImage = new QImage(w, h, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    dImage = new QImage(w, h, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    frameGrab = new QTimer(this);
}
void DisplayWidget::SetupGui()
{
    QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    layout->addWidget(view);
    setLayout(layout);

    scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, IM_PIXEL_WIDTH, IM_PIXEL_HEIGHT);
    view->setGeometry(0, 0, IM_PIXEL_WIDTH + 2*BORDER_WIDTH, IM_PIXEL_HEIGHT + 2*BORDER_WIDTH);
    view->setScene(scene);
    bModeItem->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*bImage).scaled(QSize(IM_PIXEL_WIDTH, IM_PIXEL_HEIGHT)));
    dModeItem->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*dImage).scaled(QSize(IM_PIXEL_WIDTH, IM_PIXEL_HEIGHT)));
    connect(frameGrab, SIGNAL(timeout()),this, SLOT(GenerateNewData()));
    frameGrab->start(500);
}
void DisplayWidget::GenerateNewData()
{
    QRgb * bImageData = (QRgb *)bImage->scanLine(0);
    QRgb * dImageData = (QRgb *)dImage->scanLine(0);

    for (int i; i < w * h; i++)
    {
        bImageData[i] = qRgba(rand() % FULLSCALE, 0, 0, FULLSCALE);
        dImageData[i] = qRgba(0, 255,0, rand() % FULLSCALE);
    }

    bModeItem->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*bImage).scaled(QSize(IM_PIXEL_WIDTH, IM_PIXEL_HEIGHT)));
    dModeItem->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*dImage).scaled(QSize(IM_PIXEL_WIDTH, IM_PIXEL_HEIGHT)));
}
```

And here's my main.

```
#include "displaywidget.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    DisplayWidget w(25,25);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: That's weird, usually the view auto-updates if you modify a property (Here pixmap) of a visible item

Comment: That's what I was expecting. If I click and continuously drag the window around, it updates at the correct refresh rate... if that gives you any hints...

Comment: This works fine for me in Windows. Maybe something is wrong with your system or there is other code that interferes with updating. Also it would have been convenient if you added define declarations to the code.

Comment: I just added my includes and defines, as well as my main. I'm not sure how they could screw this up for me. I'm using windows too. Any idea what could be "wrong" with my system?

Comment: Perhaps you could copy and paste the defines and includes you used? Maybe I am missing something or have something out of order?

Comment: Update: the problem goes away if I never set a layout for the widget. In that case, it updates as expected. Still can't get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I also get the exact same behavior if I just use a QLabel instead of a view/scene/item, and set its pixmap with my Qimage.

Comment: What are your Qt version and OS? Try to use more recent Qt version if possible.

Comment: I am using Qt 5.4 on Windows 7-64-bit. I'm using the visual studio 2013 plugin, but the same thing happens when I use QtCreator. I just updated to the last Qt, and it's doing the same thing. I'm starting to lose my mind.

Comment: The problem goes away if I never set a layout(), but comes back if I then add a update().